# How do you write a sql to combine multiple variables with underscore within each variables?

Tags: mysql

```
SQL Columns: UID, ID, First Name, Filename
```

The filename will be named as 'First name' follow by underscore, follow by UID, follow by underscore, follow by ID. So for example:

```
UID = 2
ID = 1
First Name = John
Filename = John_2_1.jpg
```

I tried:

```
Update Members Set Filename='First Name'.'_'.'UID'.'_'.ID.'.jpg'
Update Members Set Filename='First Name'&'_'&'UID'&'_'&ID&'.jpg'
```

Comment: Do you actually have spaces in your column name `First Name`?

Comment: This is a poor idea btw.

Comment: No. Only example. It's actually FirstName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `concat`

```
Update Members Set Filename=concat(`First Name`,'_',`UID`,'_',`ID`,'.jpg')
```

or

```
Update Members Set Filename=concat_ws('_',`First Name`,`UID`,`ID`,'.jpg')
```